Why at the headquarters of assassins, they are using out of date communication equipments in the John Wick Universe?
In the John Wick universe, when an assassination bounty request is being distributed and tracked, we see a group of clerks

writing names and their bounties in chalk on a blackboard
typing letters with mechnical type-writers
sending messages on computers with large CRT monitors which can only display green and black
connecting phone calls with a mechnical switch board

Is there in-universe explaination regarding why the super-rich and super-powerful assassin organisation still uses out of date technology?




Because it's elegant.

@Valorum, yeah, that is what I thought. It is similar to why people are still using Vaccum Tube Amplifier rather than pull solid state electronic amplifier
